# problem with kotlin update real database permanent loop

Tags: android, firebase, kotlin, firebase-realtime-database

First of all. Thanks to everybody this place is awesome and full of people willing to help ;)

My question: I've created a function using Realtime Database to update the same time three values from three different children in the same table. And it works perfectly well if I update just one of them.
To launch the function the user can update from none to all three values together but the problem is that when the user modify more than one of the value firebase keep in a death loop updating the values continuously

My DB

[image]

My function is here:

```
private fun guardarTokens () {

        referenciaBD2 = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("TipoUsuario")
        val tipoUsuarioDatos = HashMap<String, Any>()
        referenciaBD2.addValueEventListener(object : ValueEventListener {
            override fun onDataChange(snapshot: DataSnapshot) {
                if (snapshot.exists()) {
                    for (snapshot in snapshot.children) {
                        val tipoUsuarioInfo = snapshot.getValue(TipoUsuario::class.java)
                        if (tipoUsuarioInfo!!.descripcionUsuario == "usuario")
                            tipoUsuarioDatos["tuid"] = binding.etTokenAlumno.text.toString()
                        if (tipoUsuarioInfo!!.descripcionUsuario == "profesor")
                            tipoUsuarioDatos["tuid"] = binding.etTokenProfesor.text.toString()
                        if (tipoUsuarioInfo!!.descripcionUsuario == "administrador")
                            tipoUsuarioDatos["tuid"] = binding.etTokenAdmin.text.toString()
                        snapshot.ref.updateChildren(tipoUsuarioDatos)
                    }
                }
            }
            override fun onCancelled(error: DatabaseError) {
            }
        })
    }
```

Comment: you're triggering onDataChange inside onDataChange which is what's causing the infinite loop. I'm not too familiar with Firebase, but you might want to look into batching those updates and doing those updates outside of onDataChange.
Alternatively, read the value first and only trigger an update if the value is actually different in which case onDataChange will only trigger a further onDataChange if there's actually a changed value.

Comment: Yes I see you point but I don't know how to implement your solution

Comment: YES I fixed using  referenciaBD.addListenerForSingleValueEvent to avoid the loop because each value is updated just one time. TXH;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's not how you should update a specific element in the Realtime Database. What you're actually doing, you're downloading the entire `TipoUsuario` node on the client in order to perform a verification. That is considered a waste of resources and bandwidth. What you should do instead, is to perform a query and get only the data you  are interested in:

```
referenciaBD2 = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("TipoUsuario")
val queryByUsuario = referenciaBD2.orderByChild("descripcionUsuario").equalTo("usuario")
val tipoUsuarioDatos = HashMap<String, Any>()
queryByUsuario.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(object : ValueEventListener {
    override fun onDataChange(snapshot: DataSnapshot) {
        if (snapshot.exists()) {
            for (snapshot in snapshot.children) {
                val tipoUsuarioInfo = snapshot.getValue(TipoUsuario::class.java)
                tipoUsuarioDatos["tuid"] = binding.etTokenAlumno.text.toString()
                snapshot.ref.updateChildren(tipoUsuarioDatos)
             }
         }
    }
    override fun onCancelled(error: DatabaseError) {
        Log.d("TAG", error.getMessage()) //Never ignore potential errors!
    }
})
```

In this way, the query will **only** return the children where the `descripcionUsuario` field holds the value of `usuario`.

Comment: Hey Monrac. Have you tried my solution above, does it work?

Comment: Hello Alex yes I've just tryed but TipoUsuario is never to grow because it stores just three values so It doesn't matter to download it full. And I want to update the values with just a single click. But I take care of you onCancelled method I forgot it thx

Comment: If you're working with only three separate values, then you can create a reference for each element and read/update it separately.

Comment: Ok! I see you point I '' do that way to save some bandwith